# stackdriver: attempt to annotate instance returns 'CustomMetric data payloads must either be a list or a dict'

Tags: json, stackdriver

I am sending to stackdriver the following json trying to annotate an aws instance:

```
{ "message": "instance impaired", "annotated_by": "Ops User", "level": "WARN", "instance_id": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "event_epoch": 1484903331 }
```

It returns the error:

```
HTTP 400: Bad Request (CustomMetric data payloads must either be a list or a dict. You sent: <type 'NoneType'>)
```

What is wrong with my json? What does a "dict" mean in stackdriver language. I couldn't find anything in the web about that error.

Comment: Can you post additional information, like the URI endpoint, HTTP method, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I was using a wrong endpoint. Now it is working as expected.